# could not find driver error in Laravel 5.5 for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, laravel, heroku

I have started developing with Laravel 5.5 and the app is hosted on Heroku. And I use the development server (`php artisan serve`) to run the application. But I get the following error when I try to do anything that interacts with the database. The database is hosted on Heroku. If I push all the files to Heroku and try the same thing, it works.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem in local machine? What does it mean by "could not find driver"?

Answer (score 2):

You need install PDO extension for pgsql.
If your distro is ubuntu, try:

```
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

or

```
sudo apt install php5-pgsql
```

and restart your artisan server.

Comment: Well, my OS is Windows 10. Is there a PDO extension for Windows 10?

Comment: Its simple, but what your development Environment? (Laragon, Wamp, Xampp )?  look this ref, can help you if your environment its like laragon or wamp : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

all I did to solve the error was run this command in the root folder of the project

```
composer require doctrine / dbal
```

How did it come to this?
I followed this tutorial and verified that the problem was not with mamp
https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/MySQL/Install-PostgreSQL/
so check that the error was in the project and not in the local server

the problem was the following

```
Undefined type 'Doctrine \\ DBAL \\ Driver \\ PDOConnection
```

the problem was in

```
 C: \ MAMP \ htdocs \ project \ vendor \ laravel \ framework \ src \ Illuminate \ Database \ Connectors \ Connector.php
```